# Obtener un objeto JSON, enviado como parametro de un ajax, con asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

Este es mi js.

```
$('#tablaDemo').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../Paginas/Crmedu_LstCliente.aspx/getDemo",
                data: function (d) {
                    console.log(d);
                    return JSON.stringify({ parameters: d , dato: "{value: 'Vitmar'}", midat: "Hola mundo"});
                }
            }
        });
```

y este es mi metodo.

```
public static void getDemo(object parameters, object dato, string midat)
    {
       log.Info(String.Format("FORMAT REQ ========== >>>"+midat)); 
       //Request
       //var req = DataTableParameters.Get(parameters);
}
```

como recojo en `value` de `dato`, sin tener que crear modelos o algo asi, obvien lo de parameters.

por ejemplo `midat` si llega el valor. pero de del json?

Comment: pudes tratar recibiendo un [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) lo cual permite resibir tipos anonimos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.Net realiza un gran trabajo mapeando parámetros JSON serializados en tipos .NET, con lo que es innecesario realizar una doble serialización de tu objeto JSON mediante la llamada `JSON.stringify`

.NET ya realiza correctamente el mapeo de datos por convención.

Para acceder a los datos de un objeto JSON:

```
var data = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'};
```

En tu método `getDemo` te valdría declarar el parámetro como `Dictionary<string, object> data`

De esa forma ya puedes acceder a sus propiedades:

```
string key1 = data["key1"].ToString();
```

Más info útil en el siguiente [enlace](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/)

Answer (score 1):

Es como dice david_rprada, lo único que agregaría es que te recomiendo crear tipos específicos para recibir en tus controladores y no simplemente objects, .NET se va a encargar de des-serializarlos correctamente por vos.

Comment: saludos Leonardo, te recomiendo que muevas esta respuesta a un comentario en la pregunta de @david_rprada porque encaja perfectamente como comentario que como respuesta :D

Comment: Me dice "Debes tener 50 de reputación para comentar"

Comment: los tendrás dentro de poco :)